# How do I plot a slope field using mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, differential-equations

I am trying to plot slope fields of some differential equations using mathematica but can't figure it out. Say I have the equation

```
    y' = y(t) 
    y(t) = C * E^t
```

How do I plot the slope field?

I found an example but way to complex for me to understand
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SlopeFields/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command you need (since version 7) is [`VectorPlot`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcIKs.png). There are good examples in the documentation.

I think the case that you're interested in is a differential equation

```
y'[x] == f[x, y[x]]
```

In the case you gave in your question,

```
f[x_, y_] := y
```

Which integrates to the exponential

```
In[]:= sol = DSolve[y'[x] == f[x, y[x]], y, x]
Out[]= {{y -> Function[{x}, E^x c]}}
```

We can plot the slope field 
(see [wikibooks:ODE:Graphing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Graphing_1)) using

```
VectorPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: y]

This can be plotted with the solutions to the DE using something like

```
Show[VectorPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 8}, 
   VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03]],
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[x] /. sol, {c, -10, 10, 1}]], {x, -2, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: y again]

Maybe a more interesting example is the Gaussian

```
In[]:= f[x_, y_] := -x y

In[]:= sol = DSolve[y'[x] == f[x, y[x]], y, x] /. C[1] -> c
Out[]= {{y -> Function[{x}, E^(-(x^2/2)) c]}}

Show[VectorPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 8}, 
  VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0.026]],
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[x] /. sol, {c, -10, 10, 1}]], {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: -xy]

---

Finally, there is a related concept of the gradient field, where you look at the gradient (vector derivative) of a function:

```
In[]:= f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
       D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]
       VectorPlot[%, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]

Out[]= {y Cos[x y], x Cos[x y]}
```

[image: Sin[x y]]

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from the demonstration you linked that it takes a function f(x,y) but you have a set of differentials. However, knowing that `f(x,y)=y(x)'`, you could just use **`f(x,y)=C*E^x`** where `x=t`. My Differentials might be a little rusty, but I'm pretty sure that's right.

Comment: anyone got a 1 liner for slope fields?

Comment: 1 liner? If you need to know how to put it in you can check http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=152157 It's a bit more than one line as Mathematica apparently needs a library imported then the call the the plotting function itself is a bit more.